# Why doesn't this filtered noise signal behave like I expect it should?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

For my bachelor thesis I'm creating a toolkit. I've programmed a number of functions but one of them does not behave like I expect it to behave.

---

First I created the function below. It creates random white noise, plots it in the power frequency domain "assuming" it is already in this domain (for simulation purposes). Then, an inverse Fourier transform is applied to obtain the simulated signal whereafter a regular Fourier transform is applied to obtain the white noise I'd created myself. This last step is to verify whether the function behaves as I expect it to, and it does.

```python
def white_noise(n: int, N: int, slope: int = grad):
    x = np.linspace(1, 100, n)
    slope_loglog = (10 ** (slope * np.log10(x) + 1))

    whitenoise = rnd.rand(n, N)
    whitenoise_power = whitenoise ** 2  # quadratic of the white noise to retrieve the power spectrum

    whitenoise_filtered = (whitenoise_power.T * slope_loglog).T
    whitenoise_signal = fft.ifft(whitenoise_filtered)
    whitenoise_retransformed = fft.fft(whitenoise_signal)

    return whitenoise, whitenoise_filtered, whitenoise_signal, whitenoise_retransformed, slope_loglog
```

After this, I checked by plotting the results if my generated and double transformed white noise are the same. As one can see in the figure below, they are identical, thus verifying my script works.

[image: first figure]

---

Now, my problem shows. In a modified version of the script above (see below). My generated and double transformed white noise do not behave the same. The modified script adds the functionality of `modified_roll` (a small function that rolls the function over itself to simulate a disturbance shifting in time).

```python
def white_noise_signal_shift(n: int, N: int, num: int, shift: int, operations: int):
    whitenoise, whitenoise_filtered, whitenoise_signal = white_noise(n, N)[:3]

    # only showing the selected arrays
    arrays_to_select = random_arrays(N, num)
    selected_whitenoise = whitenoise[:, arrays_to_select].copy()
    selected_whitenoise_filtered = whitenoise_filtered[:, arrays_to_select].copy()
    selected_whitenoise_signal = whitenoise_signal[:, arrays_to_select].copy()

    # shifting the signal as a field of different refractive index would do
    if operations == 0:
        shifted_signal = selected_whitenoise_signal
    else:
        shifted_signal = modified_roll(selected_whitenoise_signal.copy(), shift, operations)

    # fourier transform back to the power frequency domain
    shifted_whitenoise = fft.fft(shifted_signal)

    return selected_whitenoise, selected_whitenoise_filtered, selected_whitenoise_signal, shifted_signal, \
           shifted_whitenoise
```

As one might see, filling in `white_noise_signal_shift(n, N, N, 0, 0)` like this should be equal to `white_noise(n, N)` (given you are using a `numpy.random.seed())`. However, for a big `N` it is not, which can be seen in the figure below. In both scripts, the step to get back in the power-frequency domain is `fft.fft("signal")` and as one can see the signals in the figure are identical as well. What am I doing wrong?

[image: second figure]

---

Copy this to get the result from the second figure.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.fft as fft
import numpy.random as rnd

grad = -5/3.

def white_noise(n: int, N: int, slope: int = grad):
    x = np.linspace(1, 100, n)
    slope_loglog = (10 ** (slope * np.log10(x) + 1))

    whitenoise = rnd.rand(n, N)
    whitenoise_power = whitenoise ** 2  # quadratic of the white noise to retrieve the power spectrum

    whitenoise_filtered = (whitenoise_power.T * slope_loglog).T
    whitenoise_signal = fft.ifft(whitenoise_filtered)
    whitenoise_retransformed = fft.fft(whitenoise_signal)

    return whitenoise, whitenoise_filtered, whitenoise_signal, whitenoise_retransformed, slope_loglog

# random array selection
def random_arrays(N: int, num: int):
    res = np.asarray(range(N))
    rnd.shuffle(res)
    return res[:num]


def modified_roll(inp, shift: int, operations: int):
    count = 0
    array = inp[:]
    array_rolled = array.copy()
    for k in range(operations):
        count += shift
        array = np.roll(array, shift, axis=0)
        array[:count] = 0
        array_rolled += array

    out = array_rolled / operations
    return out

def white_noise_signal_shift(n: int, N: int, num: int, shift: int, operations: int):
    whitenoise, whitenoise_filtered, whitenoise_signal = white_noise(n, N)[:3]

    # only showing the selected arrays
    arrays_to_select = random_arrays(N, num)
    selected_whitenoise = whitenoise[:, arrays_to_select].copy()
    selected_whitenoise_filtered = whitenoise_filtered[:, arrays_to_select].copy()
    selected_whitenoise_signal = whitenoise_signal[:, arrays_to_select].copy()

    # shifting the signal as a field of different refractive index would do
    if operations == 0:
        shifted_signal = selected_whitenoise_signal
    else:
        shifted_signal = modified_roll(selected_whitenoise_signal.copy(), shift, operations)

    # fourier transform back to the power frequency domain
    shifted_whitenoise = fft.fft(shifted_signal)

    return selected_whitenoise, selected_whitenoise_filtered, selected_whitenoise_signal, shifted_signal, \
           shifted_whitenoise

# this plots white_noise_signal_shift
def plt_white_noise_signal_shift(n: int, N: int, num_ar: int, shift, operations, size=(10, 7.5)):

    whitenoise, whitenoise_filtered, whitenoise_signal, shifted_signal, shifted_whitenoise \
        = white_noise_signal_shift(n, N, num_ar, shift, operations)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=size)

    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 2), (0, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=2)
    ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 2), (1, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
    ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 2), (2, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)
    ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 2), (1, 1), rowspan=1, colspan=1, sharey=ax2)
    ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((3, 2), (2, 1), rowspan=1, colspan=1, sharey=ax3)

    ax1.set_title('1) Original white noise')
    ax2.set_title('2) Filtered original white noise'), ax2.set_ylabel('Log(P)'), ax2.set_xlabel('Log(f)')
    ax3.set_title('3) Original signal')
    ax4.set_title('5) White noise from the shifted signal'), ax4.set_ylabel('Log(P)'), ax4.set_xlabel('Log(f)')
    ax5.set_title('4) Shifted signal')

    # plotting the whitenoise
    ax1.plot(whitenoise)

    # plotting white the original data
    ax2.loglog(whitenoise_filtered)
    ax3.plot(whitenoise_signal)

    # plotting the shifted data
    ax4.loglog(shifted_whitenoise)
    ax5.plot(shifted_signal)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


rnd.seed(50)

# to run the script
plt_white_noise_signal_shift(100, 50, 50, 0, 0)
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo At the bottom of my question I've pasted the script so that you are able to run it. I'm reasonably new as a poster on StackOverflow so I'm not acquainted with all the rules, but happy to learn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compute the FFT, you should always explicitly specify along which axis you intend to do so. By default, `numpy.fft.fft` computes along the *last* axis, but in your code you should be using the first one instead. For all calls to `fft` and `ifft`, add the `axis` argument:

```py
whitenoise_signal = fft.ifft(whitenoise_filtered, axis=0)
```

---

Another problem in your code is that you are not considering the symmetry in the frequency spectrum that is expected for real-valued signals, and you're not generating a complex-valued frequency spectrum to begin with. This leads to a complex-valued time signal, which I think is not what you're after. You could generate white noise and filter it in this way:

```py
def white_noise(n: int, N: int, slope: int = grad):
    x = np.linspace(1, 100, n//2)
    slope_loglog = (10 ** (slope * np.log10(x) + 1))

    whitenoise = rnd.randn(n//2, N) + 1j * rnd.randn(n//2, N)
    whitenoise[0, :] = 0  # zero-mean noise
    whitenoise_filtered = whitenoise * slope_loglog[:, np.newaxis]

    whitenoise = np.concatenate((whitenoise, whitenoise[0:1, :], np.conj(whitenoise[-1:0:-1, :])), axis=0)
    whitenoise_filtered = np.concatenate((whitenoise_filtered, whitenoise_filtered[0:1, :], np.conj(whitenoise_filtered[-1:0:-1, :])), axis=0)

    whitenoise_signal = fft.ifft(whitenoise_filtered, axis=0)
    whitenoise_signal = np.real_if_close(whitenoise_signal)
    if np.iscomplex(whitenoise_signal).any():
        print('Warning! whitenoise_signal is complex-valued!')
    whitenoise_retransformed = fft.fft(whitenoise_signal, axis=0)

    return whitenoise, whitenoise_filtered, whitenoise_signal, whitenoise_retransformed, slope_loglog
```

I first generated complex-valued, normally distributed noise of half the signal length (this is still `n` random numbers!). Next, the `concatenate` lines generate the other half of the frequency spectrum, which is a mirrored and complex-conjugate version of the first half. The 0 frequency and the bin at the Nyquist frequency I set to zero to simplify things. These two should be real-valued. The 0 frequency should be 0 if the signal is expected to have a zero mean.

Note that the `whitenoise_signal` returned is actually not white, as its spectrum has been filtered. It is pink noise, it has higher energy in the lower frequencies.

But note also that `whitenoise_signal` is real-valued. `ifft` returns complex numbers, but the imaginary part is really close to zero (not exactly zero due to rounding errors in the FFT computations). `np.real_if_close` discards the imaginary part because it's within a small tolerance of 0.

To plot the frequency spectra, use `np.abs`:

```py
ax2.plot(np.abs(whitenoise_filtered))
ax2.set_yscale('log')
```

You should also not apply a log scaling to the x-axis, as this will look funny with the symmetric frequency spectrum. If you do want to do so, you should plot only half of the spectrum:

```
ax2.loglog(np.abs(whitenoise_filtered[0:n//2,:]))
```

Comment: First of all, thank you! This fixed most of my problems. I was aware of the fact that my white noise should be a complex number but I did not know how to address that. I was struggling with the complex numbers in my Fourier transform as well but took that for granted.
I apply that "filter" because science found out that in this field the slope of the double-log power-frequency domain is roughly around -5/3. That is what the ```modified_roll``` function is for. To study the effect of the signal traveling in time along the x-axis.

Comment: Could you explain to me why I would only plot half of the frequency spectrum. Wouldn't I miss information contained in the half I'm discarding?

Comment: @Kars: If the input signal is real-valued, then the frequency spectrum is symmetric -- half of it contains redundant information.

Comment: @Kars: Think of it this way: your signal has `n` real values, the output of the FFT has `n` complex values, which really is `2*n` real values. Half of that **must** be redundant in some way. Theory shows that those complex values have a complex-conjugate symmetry, where the value for `k=0` is equal to the complex conjugate of the value for `k=n-1`, and the same for `k=1` and `k=n-2`, `k=2` and `k=n-3`, etc. I recommend reading a good text book on signals and systems to understand this.

Comment: I've had some theory concerning complex numbers however my knowledge still is very limited. Thank you for the answers, you've been very helpful!